# Django generic login view return 'str object not callable' error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

My urls.py in myProject is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testapp import urls

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(urls)),
)
```

and my urls.py in myApp (called testapp) is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testapp.forms import UsersForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'testapp/templates/login.html', 'authentication_form':'UsersForm'}),
)
```

My myProject/templates/login.html is

```
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib/auth.views.login' %}">{% csrf_token%}
            {{form.username.label_tag}}
            {{form.username}}
            {{form.password.label_tag}}
            {{form.password}}
        <input type="submit" value="login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        </form>
```

Now, when I runserver and go to 127.0.0.1 it says

```
TypeError at /

'str' object is not callable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object is not callable
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py   in login, line 53
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in  get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,    **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in   sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  69.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
  53.         form = authentication_form(request)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am using the generic login view which django provides. Why is it giving me an error at line 53 in the generic login view? In my urls.py I did specify that 'authentication_form':'UsersForm'. Am I importing the UsersForm incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear out Thomas's answer, which is right. 
Pass the form itself, not the string:

```
from testapp.forms import UsersForm
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'testapp/templates/login.html', 'authentication_form':UsersForm}),
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the actual form class for `"authentication_form"` not the name `"UsersForm"`.

Comment: hm what do you mean? My class is called UsersForm from the Model called Users.

"class UsersForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
 model = Users"