# Django giving syntax error when importing urls.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls, django-authentication, django-errors

My testProject/urls.py is this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testapp import urls
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'testproject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^testproject/', include('testproject.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^', include(urls)),
)
```

and my testApp/urls.py is this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testapp.forms import UsersForm
from templates import login.html

urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'testproject/templates/login.html', 'authentication_form':UsersForm}),
```

)

Now, when I run the server by doing

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it gives me a

```
SyntaxError at /
```

error saying

```
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 3)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 3)
Exception Location: /home/ayman/Documents/djcode/testproject/testproject/urls.py in   <module>, line 2
```

and the traceback is

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/ayman/Documents/djcode/testproject/testproject/urls.py" in <module>
  2. from testapp import urls

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
Exception Value: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 3)
```

Any idea why it is raising a Syntax Error? It's weight because some place it says that the error is in line 3 while other places say it is in line 2. Do note that this was working just a few minutes ago until I decided to change and use Django's generic login view. I had a error passing the Form as an authentication_form and I fixed that error but right after I fixed that error, this Syntax Error was raised.

The previous problem about passing the Form as an authentication_form can be viewed here as a reference

[Django generic login view return 'str object not callable' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469883/django-generic-login-view-return-str-object-not-callable-error)

just encase it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in testapp.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testapp.forms import UsersForm
from templates import login.html

urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'testproject/templates/login.html', 'authentication_form':UsersForm}),
)
```

`from templates import login.html` is not something you should import since it is not python source. You can do with just removing this line. Because the view only expects a string as parameter for template_name and does not require a Python object.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following in testProject/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
      url(r'^', include('testapp.urls')),
)
```

Another way to do this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testapp.urls import urlpatterns as testapp_urls
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
      url(r'^', include(testapp_urls)),
)
```

Also read the following section of the docs, regarding `include`: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: Strange, it is now giving me a NameError saying that "name 'testapp' is not defined" at the line "url(r'^', include('testapp.urls'))," .. I tried making it testproject.testapp.urls and then it gave a Name error saying that "name 'testproject' is not defined". My project is called testproject and the app is called testapp. Should I have an import statement importing testproject?

Comment: have you included testapp in INSTALLED_APPS at your settings.py?

Comment: Yup, in my settings.py I do have testapp under INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Strange, that's the way it should work. It looks like you've forgotten the quotes in 'testapp.urls'. Anyway, I have added one more way to do that in the answer - please try.

Comment: hm weird, I tried the new way and now it is giving me a syntax Error at the line "from testapp.urls import urlpatterns as testapp_urls"

Comment: Ah, okay thanks for your help with this issue and the previous issue as well. EWit's solution did solve the problem.

Comment: No problem! But for your future experience with Django note that the parts we've edited were also incorrect.